# Ember.computed.filter performance

Tags: performance, ember.js

In my ember app, I have a list of users that is filterable and sortable. In order to achieve the filtering and sorting, I am using an `Ember.computed.filter` and `Ember.computed.sort` computed properties that build on each other, like so (truncated for brevity):

```
Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortField: 'nickname',
    sortDir: 'asc',
    sortedUsers: Ember.computed.sort('filteredUsers', 'usersSorting'),

    usersSorting: Ember.computed('sortField', 'sortDir', function() {
        return [this.get('sortField') + ':' + this.get('sortDir')];
    },

    filteredUsers: Ember.computed.filter('model', function() {
        //[...matching logic here that uses filNickname, filAgeMin, ect...]
        return matchesFilters;
    }).property('model', 'filNickname', 'filAgeMin', 'filAgeMax' 'filGender')

})
```

My question is, when used like this, are the `Ember.computed.filter` and `Ember.computed.sort` computed properties supposed to return a brand new array each time they recompute, and therefore cause my entire `{{each sortedUsers}}` list to re-render, or is it only supposed to remove/add/rearrange array elements in the same array, so that only those individual list items are modified in the DOM?

The reason I ask is because in my initial testing, it seems like the entire list is definitely being re-rendered each time, and was wondering if maybe its due to how I'm implementing these properties. While I don't know much on the subject, from glancing at `Ember.computed.filter/sort`'s internals, it looks like they use `arrayComputed`, which I thought was not supposed to create a new array each time.

A follow up question: This list will also most likely contain a relatively large number of users at some point, easily in the hundreds. Similar to how (I'm assuming) `Ember.computed.filter` works, is there a way to limit the number of items that are rendered, to create a paginated or "Click to load more" type infinite list, without resorting to using something like `Array.slice`, which again, would cause a new array to be created, and re-render the entire list?

Comment: For your slice question http://balinterdi.com/2014/05/22/make-your-own-computed-property-macro-in-emberjs.html may be helpful. It covers creating your own computed property macro for slice